# Opencart : Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in catalog/model/extension/module/so_megamenu.php line 373

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I'm getting the following multiple error in opencart while trying to install a new there "eMarket":

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
> /home/nawadurg/shop.thekirtipur.com/catalog/model/extension/module/so_megamenu.php
> on line 373

The line 373 has the following code:

```
$output[] = array(
'name' => @unserialize($row['name']),
            'content_width' => intval($row['content_width']),
            'content_type' => $row['content_type'],
            'html' => $html,
            'product' => array(
                'name' => $product['name'],  //line 373
                'link' => $product_link,
                'image' => $product_image,
                'price' => $price,
                'special' => $special
            ),
            'categories' => $categories,            'manufactures' => $manufactures,            'subcategory' => $subcategory,          'productlist' => $productlist,          'images'    => $images,             'class_menu'    => $row['class_menu'],
            'submenu' => $this->getSubmenu($row['id'])
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error is saying is that $product variable is of type boolean (true or false) rather than an array which can have elements accessible with the ['element_name'] way.
Im guessing $product is false, as the result of what ever function setting it returning false from not finding any matching product data.

If everything works and your only problem is the error, you can just conditionally include/exclude this code with somthing like if($product){  }

Can you alternatively all the earlier code that sets $product.